# What's the difference b/w minitest-rails and minitest-spec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, minitest

Looking into using Minitest for an existing Rails 3.2.
I'm trying to understand the difference between minitest-rails and minitest-spec-rails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main differences between [minitest-spec-rails](https://github.com/metaskills/minitest-spec-rails) and [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) is the scope of the problems they solve.

### minitest-spec-rails

minitest-spec-rails overrides the test infrastructure that Rails provides by default and adds the ability to use the Minitest Spec DSL and matchers in your tests. This means that you don't have to make any changes to your existing tests to start using the Spec DSL. It also means that the Spec DSL is available in every test.

### minitest-rails

minitest-rails adds the ability to use the Spec DSL, but also changes the approach to how tests are written. It provides new generators for your tests, and allows you to choose from the TDD-style assertions or the BDD-style expectations. It places test files in more sensible locations.

It also allows your existing tests to live side by side with your new Minitest tests. You have the option to override the default test infrastructure similar to minitest-spec-rails, but you also have the option to leave them untouched.

*Disclosure: I am the author of minitest-rails*

Comment: Rails have built-in support for minitest. What are the advantages of using minitest-rails? Can you please explain this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

With minitest-spec-rails, we have a working solution by replacing MiniTest::Spec as the superclass for ActiveSupport::TestCase. This solution is simple and does not require you to recreate a new test case in your test_helper.rb or to use generators supplied by gems like minitest-rails.

Minitest changes for testing within Rails. Your test classes will inherit from MiniTest::Rails::ActiveSupport::TestCase a opposed to ActiveSupport::TestCase. You can use the MiniTest::Spec DSL. You can generate test files with the standard model, controller, resource, and other generators.

```
rails generate model User
```

or

And you can specify generating the tests using the MiniTest::Spec DSL on any of the generators by providing the --spec option

```
rails generate model User --spec
```

Comment: Can you compare/contrast with `minitest-rails`?

Comment: This is describing `minitest-rails`. With `minitest-spec-rails` your existing tests should just work, and you can use the MiniTest::Spec DSL in any of the tests. That said, I'm working on making `minitest-rails` less obtrusive while allowing you to maintain separate Test::Unit and MiniTest tests.

Comment: So just to be clear, either use one or the other, not both correct?